# Most efficient way to query with two keys in either order?

Tags: php, database, algorithm, hashmap

I have some data I receive of the following format:

```
{ gameId: 1, playerId: "john", score: .12 }
{ gameId: 1, playerId: "mary", score: .75 }
{ gameId: 1, playerId: "jane", score: .32 }
{ gameId: 2, playerId: "john", score: .89 }
{ gameId: 2, playerId: "mary", score: .91 }
{ gameId: 2, playerId: "jane", score: .99 }
```

And I want to expose these endpoints:

`GET games` => get a list of all games

`GET games/{id}` => list all the games for the `gameId` and the average score among all players

`GET players` => get a list of all games

`GET players/{id}` => list all the scores for the player and their average score across all games

So setting DBs aside for a moment, I thought of a hash map approach where I basically have two maps:

`gameScores[gameId][playerId] = score`

`playerScores[playerId][gameId] = score`

This way I could very efficiently return results as the following:

`GET games` => `array_keys(gameScores)`

`GET games/{id}` => `['average' => avg(gameScores[id]), 'games' => gameScores[id]]`

`GET players` => `array_keys(playerScores)`

`GET players/{id}` => `['average' => avg(playerScores[id]), 'games' => playerScores[id]]`

This seems like a very efficient way to return results in near O(1) time, but is it too great a drawback to be duplicating the dataset by 2? Imagine if `score` was some very large object instead.

I'm doing this in PHP, so not using something like a Python tuple solution here, but I feel like this problem is very generalizable (hash map with 2 keys) and I'm wondering if there's a better way to approach this rather than duplicating the hash map for both key orders.

Is using a database the only more optimal approach here? If so, would it be best to enter the data into a single table with those 3 columns, or should I be splitting the tables?

Comment: How many records are in your data set?

Comment: For practical purposes, not too many records (e.g. thousands) but I am wondering how the approach should change as the data set goes from small to large

Answer (score 0):

You only need one array and search it with

```
array_search($search, array_column($array, $field));
```